# Python development: Server Handling

Tags: python, django, server

This might be a very dumb question, so please bear with me (there's also no code included either).
Recently, I switched from `PHP` to `Python` and fell in love with `Django`. Locally, everything works well.
However, how are these files accessed when on a **real** server?
Is the `manage.py runserver` supposed to be used in a server environment?
Do I need to use `mod_python` ?
Coming from `PHP`, one would simply use `Apache` or `Nginx` but how does the deployment work with `Python/Django`?

This is all very confusing to me, admittedly. Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Many people choose nginx and gunicorn for live serving.  It uses the same wsgi.py file that was created with your project.  There is a section on the django site discussing deployment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manage.py runserver` is only used to speed your development process, it shouldn't be run on your server. It's similar to the newly introduced php's built-in server `php -S host:port`.

Since you're coming from PHP you can use apache with `mod_wsgi` in order to serve your django application, there are a lot of tutorials online on how to configure it properly. You might want to read what `wsgi` is and why it's important.

Comment: You say `mod_wsgi` and @joel says `nginx` - what is better now?

Comment: as a start go with mod_wsgi. nginx would require you to learn yet another service in order to serve your application and I don't recommend that unless you really want to. `request->mod_wsgi->app` vs `request->nginx->gunicorn/uwsgi/other->app`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!